# How to adjust width of flex-box child relative to the width of its sibling flex-box

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Sorry if you are not able to understand my question.I'm working on rock-paper-scissor project in which user play the game against computer.You can check https://coderoo7.github.io/rockPaperScissor/
Now when user select any option(rock,paper or scissor) than computer show its choice(either rock or paper or scissor).But show its choice than image appear is bigger in size than the images on left side(user view).

How can I make images appear on both side of same size they are children of flexbox class.

```html
<section id="player">
                    <div class="score">
                        <h2>Your Score</h2>
                        <span class="scoreDisplay">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemSelection">
                        <button class="btn" value="rock"><img src="img/rock.svg" alt=""></button>
                        <button class="btn" value="paper"><img src="img/paper.svg" alt=""></button>
                        <button class="btn" value="scissors"><img src="img/scissors.svg" alt=""></button>
                    </div>
                </section>
 <section id="computer">
                    <div class="score">
                        <h2>Computer Score</h2>
                        <span class="scoreDisplay">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="itemInsert">
                     here I insert image(rock,paper or scissor) using JavaScript. But size of image is bigger than in "itemSelection" class. 
                    </div>
 </section>
```

For reference you can check my code using inspect element.And play the game in mobile-view, then you can understand what I am trying to say...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the elements `width` is set in percentage (70%), so when you got 3 elements inside 1 container each element will get 1/3 of the entire space of the container, but in the other container you only got 1 element, than its taking the entire space (well 70% of it).

A quick fix for that is to add 2 more elements but hide them, this way the visible element will take up 1/3 of the container's space same as the other elements in the first container.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile view, by examining your image sizes under the `.itemSelection` class, they have a height of `39.33px`, which means you can solve this issue by,

1. adding a class `pc-selection` to the image that is inside the class `.itemInsert`,

```
<div class="itemInsert">
    <img class="pc-selection">
</div>
```

2. add a media query for the `.pc-selection` class,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  img.pc-selection {
    height: 39.33px;
  }
}
```